# Enumerating all the objects on the stage - unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm not doing a great game on unity. I want to make a save function. It will work so that when you click on the button, each object in unity will be recorded, along with its Position scripts and so on. But I did not understand how to sort through all the objects on the stage, I hope that someone from those sitting here will help me. There may be errors in the text, I used google translator.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the objects in a scene and iterate over them to find the desired data by:

```
    //GameObject[] allGameObjects = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>(); // Ignore this as per derHugo's comment, use the line below
    GameObject[] allGameObjects = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().GetRootGameObjects();

    foreach (GameObject go in allGameObjects)
    {
        Debug.Log("Name: " + go.name);
        Component[] components = go.GetComponents<Component>();
        foreach (Component comp in components)
        {
            Debug.Log("Component: " + comp.GetType());
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**  As derHugo pointed out in the comments on this answer, using FindObjectsOfType will only return active GameObjects, so I've modified the answer.  You will also need to add `using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;`  If you want to save objects in other scenes you can target them by name or index using [other methods and properties of the SceneManager class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html)

Comment: That goes only through the active GameObjects though ;) you'ld be better using [`Scene.GetRootGameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene.GetRootGameObjects.html)